# Debugging EF App locks DB tables?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a WCF App that has 5-6 EF Models in it.  In a production env, only one instance of this app will be running.

But in development there are 5 developers working on it at the same time.  (Against the same Database.)

We are noticing that sometimes tables on our SQL Server 2008 R2 DB get locked.  It seems to be when someone is doing step over debugging and has to leave it on a step for a few minutes.

I am curious why EF would keep a lock on a table.  How would someone keep an lock on a table using EF?  What Can I do to prevent this?

NOTE: This same application accesses a WCF Data Services (OData) endpoint to get some of its data (from the same database).  I don't see how OData would be locking the db, but I thought I would mention it in case it is important.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one solution. Each developer will have locally installed database and run debugging session in his own environment! Anything else is wrong development environment. Use SQL Server Express or SQL Server Developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

All we can do is venture various guesses. Eg. if your data model is missing proper indexes then record lookups turn into table scans and scans [escalate locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172010.aspx) to table level.

The real solution is to investigate the blocking properly. What is causing the block, exactly, what resource is waiting on? What session/transaction/statement is holding the resource needed by what other session/transaction/statement.

Use the [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx) or  [who_is_active](http://whoisactive.com) or [sp_blitz](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/). Read the [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) whitepaper.